# Random number in a certain interval with a exponential distribution

Tags: matlab, math, probability

I'd like to generate a random number in a certain interval using an exponential distribution. My problem is that if I use exprnd I can't control the interval, I can only give a mean value, but that doesn't suit my needs. 
Is there another function or is there some trick that I have to use?

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and it doesn't work. Even if the uniform distribution is between 0 and 1 and I set lambda(in this article's case theta) to 1 I still get values above 1. I'd like to have an exponential distribution between 0 and 1

Comment: It is not very clear what you want exactly. The exponential distribution has support $[0, \infty]$. You want a distribution in $[a,b]$, in what sense should it be exponential?

Comment: What do you mean? exponential distribution is supported on the unlimited interval `[0,+\infty)`.

Comment: @MitchWheat user doesn't want an exponential distribution from a uniform. He already has a function to sample from the exponential.

Comment: Well, let's say that a is 0 and b is 1 and lambda is 1. In this case I'd like to have a very high probility of having a 0, but a very low probability of getting a 1.

Comment: I would even settle for [0,+\infty), but even if I use exprnd, I have to give a mean. I'd like it generate random numbers in accordance to the PDF with Lambda = 1. But I'd still much rather have it in [a,b].

Comment: thus, probably you don't want an exponential distribution. say that `X` distributes exponentially you may want to map it on your interval through a measurable invertible function `f`, so that `Y =f(X)` is supported on `[a,b)`. Point is: which `f` do you want? You may build something you need modifying the `arctan` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? (or have I misunderstood the problem?)

```
%#Set the parameters
T = 2000; %#Number of observations to simulate
Mu = 0.5; %#Exponential distribution parameter
LB = 0; %#Lower bound on exponential distribution
UB = 1; %#Upper bound on exponential distribution

%#Validate the parameters
if LB < 0 || UB < 0; error('Bounds must be non-negative'); end
if Mu <= 0; error('Mu must be positive'); end

%#Determine LB and UB in terms of cumulative probabilities
LBProb = expcdf(LB, Mu);
UBProb = expcdf(UB, Mu);

%#Simulate uniform draws from the interval LBProb to UBProb
Draw = LBProb + (UBProb - LBProb) .* rand(T, 1);

%#Convert the uniform draws to exponential draws using the inverse cdf
X = expinv(Draw, Mu);
```

Comment: I guess user doesn't need to obtain exponential from uniform map, rather to remap exponential itself.

Comment: @Acorbe Perhaps... I'm not sure user has a mathematical formulation in mind of what user wants :-) But nonetheless, this is one way to solve the problem as stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this gets me the results that I want.

Comment: @user1797895 Glad I could help. I think the comments are fairly self-explanatory, but let me know if you'd like a more detailed explanation and I can add one. Cheers.

Comment: @user1797895 You realize for this you still need to define lambda (in this case 0.5), right? It is essentially the same as my second suggestion.

Comment: You're right. It uses the same principle.

Answer (score 3):

Exponential distribution is supported on `[0,+\infty)`. You may want to remap it on `[0,1)` using some [measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) invertible map `f`, so that `Y = f(X)` is a random variable supported on `[0,1)`.

Problem: you have to build such an `f`.

My suggestion is

```
 f(x) = 2/pi * arctan(x).
```

The function `arctan` maps `(-\infty,\infty)` to `(-pi/2,pi/2)`. Because you are considering just positive samples (because your `X` goes exponentially) you will obtain samples in `[0,pi/2)`; thus, you have to rescale by `2/pi`. Moreover, because the MacLaurin expansion of `arctan` is `x+o(x)`, you have samples that go exactly exponentially close enough to the origin.

Now, if you sample from whatever exponential (i.e. using possibly any value of `\lambda` - preferably small) and you evaluate `f` on the sample, you get samples that concentrate as you like (i.e. close to `0` and nearly exponential).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

Sample from the exponential distribution with lambda=1, and reject any number outside of your intended interval. If your interval is [0,1], you have a probability of ~0.63 to get a number in that interval. That means a 99% probability of getting a "good" number after 10 samples.

Another possibility is to choose a high enough number n, such that the probability of sampling something over n is sufficiently small. For lambda = 1, n=1000 would suffice. Then you just sample from the exponential and transform it to your random sample by a+(b-a)*(sample/n)

Comment: The problem is that I can't generate random numbers given lambda in the PDF - that would solve all my problems. I have to give a mean, which really goes against everything I'm doing.

Comment: What I'd like is to get output in the same format as for example  unifrnd(0,1,1, 10) , but with an exponential distribution.

Comment: You don't want to give a mean, but you want "an exponential distribution"? What does this mean? You need to decide what kind of distribution you want...